# list comprehension does not return empty list

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I tried to find the relevant question but couldn't find so creating a new one. 
My program creates a new list using list comprehension in python as per a simple if condition.

```
  Newone = [ temp for temp in Oldone if temp % 2 != 0 ]
```

It works fine but when in some situation it doesn't work. For example this one

```
 Oldone = [1]
 Newone = [ temp for temp in Oldone if temp % 2 != 0 ]
```

This returns [1] but i am expecting Newone to be []

Comment: Why? 1 % 2 == 1.

Comment: `1 % 2 == 1`, which is != 0

Comment: Why are you expecting that? `1 % 2` is `1` which is not zero, so the returned list is the correct list.

Comment: Because it's satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 1%2 == 1
```

So your your condition: `temp % 2 != 0` is `True`, therefore it is included in the list. If you want an empty list, you should change it `temp % 2 == 0`.

Comment: I got what i was doing wrong, I was checking the condition twice. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure what's happening. Your list comprehension:

```
 Newone = [ temp for temp in Oldone if temp % 2 != 0 ]
```

Means; put in my new list `Newone` all `temp` values from my existing list `Oldone`, which satisfy the condition `temp % 2 != 0` (Essentially keep only odd numbers, since the remainder is 1, whenever an odd number is divided by 2)

Comment: I wanted to remove all odd values and was doing exactly opposite. When i changed it to == 0 it solved my problem.